# Valor duplicado ERROR, pero necesito identificar el campo

Tags: sql, insert

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Derrepente es muy simple mi pregunta pero supongo que todos estamos aqui para apoyarnos y seguir aprendiendo.

Mi problema es en esta linea de codigo:

```
INSERT INTO DEPENDIENTES VALUES (78900456,'Oscar','M',15-01-89,'Hijo');
```

el error me bota por que el numero de Cédula `78900456`, ya lo ingrese en el registro anterior.

Supongo que la solución seria "quítale el PK a la variable Cédula de DEPENDIENTES, y listo ya te permitirá agregar", pues SI, pero también me permitirá agregar el mismo registro una y otra vez.

OJO QUE PUEDO AGREGAR ese numero de cédula varias veces, por que la persona puede tener varios hijos , PERO NO TODOS LOS DATOS PUEDEN SER IGUALES "Nombre_Dep, Sexo, FechaN, Parentesco"

Por un momento tambien pense quitarel primary key a Cedula de la TABLA PERSONAS, pero  tampoco seria correcto si no como los identifico como unicos?.

- Si o si tengo que poner como FK a Cedula(DEPENDIENTES) de Cedula de PERSONAS
  por que es la única manera de hacer la referencia.

Espero me puedan ayudar por que necesito Agregar esa ultima linea de codigo 
pero no me permita porque es un valor duplicado.

NOTA: NO HAY MAS TABLAS SON SOLO ESAS 3

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS
(Cod_dep CHAR(2) not null primary key,
Nombre_Dep CHAR(15) not null,
Cedula_Jefe CHAR(8) not null);

CREATE TABLE PERSONAS
(Cedula CHAR(8) not null primary key,
Nombre CHAR(25) not null,
Primer_Apellido CHAR(25) not null,
Segundo_Apellido CHAR(25) not null,
Sexo CHAR(1) CHECK (Sexo IN ('M','F')),
Direccion CHAR(40) not null,
Telefono CHAR(9) not null,
Salario INT not null,
Cedula_Sup CHAR(8) not null,
Cod_dep CHAR(2) not null,
FOREIGN KEY (Cod_dep) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTOS(Cod_Dep));

CREATE TABLE DEPENDIENTES
(Cedula CHAR(8) not null primary key,
Nombre_Dep CHAR(25) not null,
Sexo CHAR(1) CHECK (Sexo IN ('M','F')),
FechaN DATETIME,
Parentesco CHAR(15) not null,
FOREIGN KEY (Cedula) REFERENCES PERSONAS(Cedula));


INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS VALUES (0,'Gerencia', 43890231);
INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS VALUES (1,'Teleinformatica', 75556734);
INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS VALUES (2,'Desarrollo', 23423445); 
INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS VALUES (3,'Soporte Tecnico', 71134534); 

INSERT INTO PERSONAS VALUES (71134534,'Juan','Mesa','Uribe','M','Cra 25 22-1','2567532',1600000,23423445,3);
INSERT INTO PERSONAS VALUES (78900456,'Carlos','Betancur','Agudelo','M','Cir. 5 12-5','4445775',1500000,75556743,1);
INSERT INTO PERSONAS VALUES (73456789,'Mario','Gómez','Angel','M','Cr. 53 23-1','3456789',1200000,23423445,2);

INSERT INTO DEPENDIENTES VALUES (78900456,'Juanita','F',12-04-95,'Hija');
INSERT INTO DEPENDIENTES VALUES (78900456,'Oscar','M',15-01-89,'Hijo');
```

Comment: Fíjate que fácil yo lo resolvería. **¿Los dependientes qué son... personas?** Entonces agrégalos a la tabla `personas`. Si `Juan` es el papá de `Juanita` ambos son ante todo **dos personas** con nombres, apellidos, cédula, etc, etc, etc. ¿Por qué tienes a Juanita en otra tabla? Cuando Juanita se case y sea mamá y tenga dependientes... entonces tendrás que **repetir** los datos de Juanita en otra tabla y te darás cuenta de haber cometido un error en tu diseño. Yo tendría **una sola tabla** que almacene todos los datos de cada persona, y una tabla que exprese la relaciones usando claves.

Comment: Si es una tabla de una empresa peor aún, supongamos que `Juanita` viene a ser mayor de edad y le dan trabajo en la misma empresa. Pues ya tienes igualmente datos duplicados en tu tabla. La `Juanita` dependiente de su papá y la `Juanita` que ahora es empleada. ¿Y cómo hago para distinguir si es empleada o no o es sólo dependiente ... mediante una columna en la tabla `personas` que indique el estatus en la empresa... o simplemente buscando si su id existe en la tabla `dependientes`.

Answer (score 0):

Diria que tu tabla dependientes nunca estará bien si tienes necesariamente una relación uno a varios entre la tabla personas y ellas.
Una solución sería incorporar una columna que conforme con la cedula del progenitor + un número correlativo lo que sí sería un primary key (combinado)
Por ahora cedula es un FK y si bien es necesario relacionarlo, el propio dependiente también tiene cedula que es irrepetible, esa sería la verdadera 
PK de tu tabla.
No sé, fijate

Comment: Exacto tmb pense eso, es decir identificar al DEPENDIENTE TMB CON SU PROPIA CEDULA, y listo ahi si ya estaria la solucion por que seria PK COMBINADA. Pero no me dan esa informacion, por lo que no me lo puedo inventar.

Comment: Entonces quitale el pk a cedula, dejala coomo FK y haz un campo autoincremental para almacenar a los familiares

Comment: Listo acabo de añadir dos imagenes, En realidad es como una practica ya, estoy haciendo ejercicios, y SOLO ME DAN ESAS IMAGENES y apartir de HAY TENGO QUE CREAR el codigo. Como podras ver no puedo inventarme la cedula del dependiente, por lo que la unica opcion es con un campo autoincremental?

Comment: Solo como referencia uno de LAS PREGUNTAS Y RESULTADO ES:

Se desea obtener la información
de todos los dependientes de las personas cuyo apellido sea BETANCUR y su sexo sea
MASCULINO.


    SELECT dependientes.*
    FROM personas, dependientes
    WHERE primer_apellido = 'Betancur'
    AND sexo = 'M'
    AND dependiente.cedula = personas.cedula

Comment: Agregá un autoincremental, que no estarías 'inventando' nada. luego podrás hacer las búsquedas que te parezca  o necesites relacionandolas con ¨Betancur y con la Cédula de Betancur

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaria quitar ese pk y crear un sp y validar y si son todos iguales que no se inserte y si algo es diferente se inserte .
algo asi :

```
create procedure insertar
@cedula nvarchar(14),
@nombre nvarchar(250),
@apellido nvarchar(250),
@pais nvarchar(250
as
begin
declare @count int
set @count=(select count(*) from tabla where cedula=@cedula and nombre=@nombre and apellido=@apellido and pais=@pais)
if @count >0
begin
select 'ya hay un registro';

end
else
begin
insert into tabla values(@cedula,@nombre,@apellido,@pais);
end
```

Ademas en un sp puede validar otra cosa que tu decees vamos todo es posible.